# command line error: DataSource not set

Tags: flyway

This is running on Windows 2008r2
with cygwin bash.

I am stuck on what is wrong here.  Hopefully I have given
the pertinent information.

```
$ sh flyway.sh migrate

Flyway (Command-line Tool) v.3.1

ERROR: DataSource not set! Check your configuration!
```

----------- file layout

- flyway.sh
- conf/flyway.properties
- drivers/sqljdbc4.jar
- sql/V2014.10.20.06.30__rgx_test_live.sql

---

### ----------- flyway.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
'/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_25/bin/java.exe' \
  -cp 'c:\gcs\apps\rgx_flyway\flyway\lib\flyway-commandline-3.1.jar;c:\gcs\apps\rgx_flyway\flyway\lib\flyway-core-3.1.jar' \
  org.flywaydb.commandline.Main \
  $@
```

---

### ----------- conf/flyway.properties

```
flyway.url=jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1;databaseName=rgx_mars;
flyway.user=auser
flyway.password=apassword
flyway.locations=filesystem:./sql
```

Comment: Please try again using the standard flyway shell script

Comment: I give up on running from the cygwin shell.  I am able to run with flyway.cmd from DOS.  I have set JAVA_HOME and all is fine.